# How to split the data 1 1 2 2 3 3 to 1 2 3 1 2 3 in R?

Tags: r

I want to convert a vector:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3
```

to

```
1 2 3 1 2 3
```

How to do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rbind/split`

```
c(do.call(rbind, split(v1, v1)))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

---

Or if there are unequal number of replications of each element, get the `order` of the `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
v1[order(rowid(v1))]
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Or with `base R`

```
v1[order(ave(v1, v1, FUN = seq_along))]
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a matrix to layout the original vector by rows and then convert it back to a vector to get the desired result.

```
v = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)

v2 = as.vector(matrix(v, nrow = length(unique(v)), byrow = T))

> v2
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

The `length(unique(v))` is there to generalize how many rows the matrix should have and not hardcode a 3.

Another example:

```
v = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
v2 = as.vector(matrix(v, nrow = length(unique(v)), byrow = T))

v2
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but keeping `as.vector` to show a clear intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
vec <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
rep(unique(vec), 2)

[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is also nice solution.Many thanks for your help.